# Run interactive batch in Visual Studio post build events

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, psexec

I have a program written in vb.net.  After I build, I want to launch an interactive batch file that executes a psexec command remotely. How can I do that?
this is my post build event:

```
call "$(ProjectDir)ExecOnGw.bat"
```

And this is my batch that if it runs in a normal command prompt, execution is ok.

```
c:\Sysinternal\psexec.exe \\gateway "C:\Remotepath\mybatch.bat" -u mydomain\myuser -p ******
pause
```

This batch calls another batch on a remote machine that does something, then if I want to exit, I have to press a "q" and "Enter". In a normal command prompt, it works fine. But in a Visual Studio post build event it goes down.
Help me!

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged with `C#`. Removed tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've done this before using the start command.  I created a simple pause.bat file to demonstrate:

```
    @echo off
    pause Press Any Key
    exit
```

If I put this in the post build event, I see a console that just closes.

```
call pause.bat
```

If I use this instead, I get a second console window that takes my input before closing.

```
start "My Process" /D c:\batch /WAIT pause.bat
```

Comment: The `start /WAIT` one is exactly what I'm looking for, surprised this answer was buried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is info about our technical development environment :

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019

  .NET Core 3.1

**Just to add to @dsway good answer, I used Visual Studio 2019’s macros so that I could keep the directory path as relative:**

> start "My Process" /D  "$(SolutionDir)Scripts" /WAIT blahblah.bat

1. Right-click on the Project in question
2. A context menu will show up
3. Select the Properties option
4. Select “Build Events”
5. Click on “Edit Post-build…”
6. Enter the aforementioned command that I posted above, and tailor it to your needs before pressing OK.

[image]